# How to find and take difference in column values in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am faced with a complicated problem of taking difference in values in rows.

Sales column shows in total sales and it is automatically updated.  I would like create a table with column SalesUpdate where it takes the difference in Sales from the two most recent Sales value in TABLE 1.

TABLE 1.

```
№   |    Date      |  Product   | Sales
---------------------------------------- 
1   | 2017-03-01   |    Coke    | 10       
2   | 2017-03-02   |    Pepsi   | 9   
3   | 2017-03-03   |    Tea     | 12
4   | 2017-03-04   |    Coke    | 20
5   | 2017-03-05   |   Coke     | 22
6   | 2017-03-06   |   Pepsi    | 15
```

TABLE 2.

```
    №  | Product   | Date                   | SalesUpdate
---------------------------------------------------------------    
    1  | Coke      |   2017-03-01           | 22-20 = 2       
    2  | Pepsi     |   2017-03-02           | 15-9 = 6 
    3  | Tea       |   2017-03-03           | 12-0 = 12
```

Comment: Why is date in Table 2 from the older sale?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite elegant solution, but, at least, not DBMS-specific :) Also, didn't get, what data you want to receive in Date column of resulting set.

```
SELECT md.product,
  md.max_Date Date, 
  (t1.sales - CASE WHEN t2.sales IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE t2.sales END) SalesUpdate
FROM (SELECT MAX(DATE) max_date,
        product
      FROM TABLE1
      GROUP BY PRODUCT) md
      INNER JOIN TABLE1 t1 ON md.product = t1.product AND md.max_date = t1.DATE
      LEFT JOIN TABLE1 t2 ON t2.product = t1.product AND t2.date < t1.date
      LEFT JOIN TABLE1 t3 ON t2.product = t3.product AND t3.date > t2.date AND t3.date < t1.date
WHERE t3.product IS NULL
```